# Syntax Error - Missing Operator - Cannot determine what is missing

Tags: sql, syntax-error

What is wrong with the SQL statement?  I get a message that there is a syntax error (missing operator).  From the ASSIGNMENT TABLE I am wanting to select all rows where ASSN_TRANS_STATE_NUM = '1'.  For each of these rows I then want to get the project name from the PROJECTS table.  I also want to get each of the Task names from the TASKS table.  I did get this to work earlier (not sure what change I made that broke it) but even when it did work it was not correct.  It was reporting every task for each of the projects, instead of just giving me the tasks specific to a project.

```
SELECT 
  TRANS.PROJ_UID, 
  PROJ.PROJ_NAME, 
  TRANS.TASK_UID, 
  TASKS.TASK_NAME, 
  TRANS.ASSN_TRANS_STATE_ENUM, 
  TRANS.ASSN_TRANS_APPROVER_RES_UID
FROM dbo_MSP_ASSIGNMENT_TRANSACTIONS TRANS 
INNER JOIN dbo_MSP_PROJECTS PROJ ON PROJ.PROJ_UID = TRANS.PROJ_UID
INNER JOIN dbo_MSP_TASKS TASKS ON TASKS.TASK_UID = TRANS.TASK_UID
WHERE TRANS.ASSN_TRANS_STATE_ENUM = 1;
```

Comment: Which database? Have you tried running the query in one of the 'sql' 'ide / gui' editors? i.e. MySql: phpmyadmin, SQLite: 'Expert Personal', Oracle: 'SQLDeveloper, Toad', etc.

Comment: Should that be 'dbo_' or 'dbo.' on the table names?

Comment: Where does the 'dbo_' prefix come from in 'dbo_MSP_ASSIGNMENT_TRANSACTIONS'? i.e. Why is it in 'lower case' and not 'upper case' to match the rest of the name? Some database engines as 'letter case' dependant, also, it makes maintenance more difficult to have to use mixed case in database 'entity' names.

Answer (score 0):

It will be dbo. rather than dbo_. I guess it should help

```
SELECT 
  TRANS.PROJ_UID, 
  PROJ.PROJ_NAME, 
  TRANS.TASK_UID, 
  TASKS.TASK_NAME, 
  TRANS.ASSN_TRANS_STATE_ENUM, 
  TRANS.ASSN_TRANS_APPROVER_RES_UID
FROM dbo.MSP_ASSIGNMENT_TRANSACTIONS TRANS 
INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_PROJECTS PROJ ON PROJ.PROJ_UID = TRANS.PROJ_UID
INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_TASKS TASKS ON TASKS.TASK_UID = TRANS.TASK_UID
WHERE TRANS.ASSN_TRANS_STATE_ENUM = 1;
```

Comment: @Dennis Kattengell, was this helpful ?